# How to execute a stored procedure and forget about it using C# and Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I am using Entity Framework for an app that I wrote using ASP.NET MVC.

I need to be able to call a stored procedure and forget about it. I don't care about the result I just want to trigger it.

I tried to accomplish that by using a separate connection for calling the stored procedure using the `ExecuteSqlCommandAsync` method. But the stored procedure does not seems to be getting fired.

Here is my async method

```
protected async Task ProcessRecords(DateTime loadedAt, string email)
{
    try
    {
        using (var conn = new AppContext())
        {
            var result = conn.Database.ExecuteSqlCommandAsync("EXEC [DedecatedProcesses] @p0, @p1;", loadedAt, email);
            await Task.WhenAll(result);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // Do something with e.Message
    }
}
```

Then from an action method with in a controller I call it like so

```
var loaded = ProcessRecords(DateTime.UtcNow, model.Email);
```

I do not get any error when I run my code but the procedure does not run.

When I execute the stored procedure using SSMS it runs with no problems.

How can I correctly call the stored procedure and forget about it?

Comment: `EXEC` is only required when there is more than one line in the statement therefore it is not necessary in your code

Comment: @Dalorzo Thanks for the hit. But any clue on how to trigger the SP and forgetting about it?

Comment: First try running  without the encapsulating async method. and Make sure you are calling the Procedure correctly.
I usually run my procs in Entity by adding it to the model by using "function import"

Comment: @DaniDev Thank you for that tip. When I called the SP using this command Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(TransactionalBehavior.DoNotEnsureTransaction, "exec ..."); it worked with no problems.

Comment: Ok that's great. My second observation is that if you want to "forgot about it" you don't want to "await" it. that in it of itself wont cause the proc to not run, if in fact its being invoked correctly, however "await" tells your  method that it has to wait for the result of that task before existing the method. It can run other command but it wont return

Comment: If you really need a-fire-and forget in ASP.NET (which is quite uncommon and may indicate a design issue), have a look at [`HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem`](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2014/06/04/queuebackgroundworkitem-to-reliably-schedule-and-run-background-processes-in-asp-net/).

Comment: How do you know that it was not running, do not you miss a commit?

Answer (score 1):

Before answering your question, I want to point this out :

You create an async Task, if "correctly" used you would already have an async call. Something wrong beforehand?

Answer :

`await` is a call that will not end your curent context by default. In this case you will wait `ExecuteSqlCommandAsync` at the end of the `try`.
You can explicitly remove this behaviour as follow :

```
protected async Task ProcessRecords(DateTime loadedAt, string email)
{
    try
    {
        using (var conn = new AppContext())
        {
            await conn.Database.ExecuteSqlCommandAsync("DedecatedProcesses @p0, @p1;", loadedAt, email)
                .ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // Do something with e.Message
    }
}
```

NB: There is no point to store your result here.